# Aligning on left (?)

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

Why the equation continues on the left side? It was always convenient for me when eq. continues on right, how to fix?

```
P'(x)=0+a_1+2a_2(x-x_0)+..+na_n(x-x_0)^{n-1}\\ P'(x_0)=a_1\\
P''(x)=0+2a_2+6a_3(x-x_0)+..+n(n-1)a_n(x-x_0)^{n-2}\\
P''(x_0)=2x_2\\
\therefore P^n(x_0)=n!a_n
```

[image]

Comment: Pardon me, but which math environment do you use? Please post a complete, compilable code

Comment: we can not run your example as it is incomplete but your image shows it all aligned to the right, what do you mean by "continues on the left side" ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using an `align` environment, or maybe an `aligned` environment, but failed to provide alignment points (`&` characters). Moreover, you may have meant to create 2 separate columns of material, with expressions involving `(x-x_0)` on the left and those involving `(x_0)` on the right.

In the following, the material within each column is aligned on the respective `=` symbols.

Note also that I changed `n!a_n` to `n!\,a_n` in the final row, replaced both instances of `..` with `\dots` (to create typographic ellipses in the left-hand column), and changed `P^n(x_0)` to `P^{(n)}(x_0)` to clarify that the expression is about the `n`-th derivative rather than about the `n`-th power of `P(x_0)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set suitable page size parameters
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{amssymb} % for '\therefore' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{aligned}
P'(x)  &= 0+\phantom{2}a_1+2a_2(x-x_0)+\dots+na_n(x-x_0)^{n-1}
    & P'(x_0) &= a_1\\
P''(x) &= 0+2a_2+6a_3(x-x_0)+\dots+n(n-1)a_n(x-x_0)^{n-2}
    & P''(x_0)&= 2x_2\\
    &&\therefore\ P^{(n)}(x_0) &= n!\,a_n
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document
```